# Wireless adapter not connected after upgrade from OpenSUSE 12.1 to 13.1

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, opensuse

After update from OpenSUSE 12.1 to 13.1, I have this problem. My wireless adapter stops working. I can't figure out anything's wrong.

Here's some infos:

- I still have an IP by DHCP (192.168.1.12) but can't ping through the gateway (192.168.1.1) hence no internet.
- In network setting, my wireless adapter (TPLINK 722N) is recognized as `not connected`
- In hardware tab, the adapter driver is `rt2800usb`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. We just need to change the usb port and rename the device. That's weird, maybe the OS still cached the device settings somewhere and that causes the conflict :(